# Average amount of products created by day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a rails beginner and I tried to write a simple application where the user can create some products. So now I'm building a statistics site, where I want to display the average amount of products that where created by day.

So my idea was to calculate:

```
@average_amount = Days_where_products_were_created / Products.all.count
```

So my problem is that I don't know how I can check on how many days Products were created? Is there a simple method? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to do the average across all the records you can use the `#minimum` and `#maximum` calculations available from ActiveRecord to find your oldest and newest records.

```
oldest = Products.minimum(:created_at)
newest = Products.maximum(:created_at)
```

Now you can create a range with those variables. For simplicity sake, convert `Time` objects to a `Date` for use in the range.

```
days_where_products_were_created = (oldest.to_date..newest.to_date).count
```

**EDIT**

If you want to base your average for only dates where products were created you could pluck the created_at `Time`, convert it to a `Date` to get rid of times, and count the unique values.

```
days_where_products_were_created = Products.pluck(:created_at).collect(&:to_date).uniq.count
```

Comment: The problem is that there are also dates were no product was created between `oldest.to_date` and `newest.to_date`

Answer (score 0):

Average amount of products created yesterday:

```
@average_amount = Products.all.count / Products.where(created_on: Date.yesterday.beginning_of_day..Date.yesterday.end_of_day).count
```

created today:

```
@average_amount = Products.all.count / Products.where(created_on: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day)
```

created 4 days ago:

```
@average_amount = Products.all.count / Products.where(created_on: (Date.today.beginning_of_day-4.days)..(Date.today.end_of_day-4.days)).count
```

Note that in your code it seems like your model is named `Products`. It should be `Product` instead, as it's a Rails convention for model names to be written in singular form.

Taking it a step further, making the code reusable:

```
from_date = Date.today - 4.days
to_date = Date.today

@average_amount = Product.all.count / Product.where(created_on: from_date.beginning_of_day..to_date.end_of_day).count
```

This way you only have to edit `from_date` & `to_date` variables accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but i want to know the amount for several days!

Comment: @JohnSmith Updated my initial answer.